# Is there a way, in background, to get my app notified when the CMMotionActivity changes?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, core-motion

I'd like to know if the system can wake an application in the background if the CMMotionActivity changes, for example, if the user starts walking/running after sitting, I'd like to be able to execute some code and schedule a local notification.

**Is there a way to ask the system to wake my app in the background for that ?**

EDIT : By looking at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionActivityManager/startActivityUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:), it doesn't seem to be possible *("[...] and updates are not delivered while your app is suspended.")*, **but maybe is there an other way ?**

Comment: Have you discovered another way to do this?

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta No, maybe the only way would be to keep the app constantly running in the background, but that requires it to do a something pretty specific, such as playing music, doing VoIP, or GPS.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta (and of course it might hurt the battery more than needed...)

Comment: There is a way using always location in background by asking for location updates you can get motion updates in background.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this creating a background timer and checking for the activity type in the selector called method. Just have a look to the code in case it can be useful for you. I accept suggestions, corrections and advices over this.

```
#define k_timer_time 10.0f
@property NSTimer *timer;

- (void) createBackGroundTimerToCheckMotion{
// create new uiBackgroundTask
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

// and create new timer with async call:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    weakSelf.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:k_timer_time target:self selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    weakSelf.timer.tolerance = 5;
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:weakSelf.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
});
```

}

```
- (void) onTick:(NStimer*)timer{
if([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable])
{
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    CMMotionActivityManager *cm = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];

    CMPedometer *sc = [[CMPedometer alloc] init];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *last30Sec = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-30];

    [cm queryActivityStartingFromDate:last30Sec toDate:now toQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(NSArray *activities, NSError *error)
     {
         [activities enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CMMotionActivity *a, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
              //Your stuff here

         }];
     }];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error accessing Motion data");
}
```

}